# Mobile Keyboard 'Go' Button Issue in Angular Project

Tags: angular, mobile, keyboard

I'm facing an issue in my Angular project related to the 'Go' button on the mobile keyboard. In the desktop version, everything works fine, but on mobile, after touching the magnifying glass icon to initiate a search, pressing the 'Go' button doesn't dismiss (disappear) the keyboard as expected. Instead, I'm forced to use the standard back button on the mobile device.

I've tried the following code suggested during my research and even asked Chat GPT:

```
onInput(event: any) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter' || event.keyCode === 13) {
    let searchElement = document.getElementById('searchInputId');
    if(searchElement)
    searchElement.blur();
  }
}
```

However, the issue persists. Do you have any insights or alternative solutions to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using (input) method for the input element, use the (keydown) method and the same code will work